# Use dkimpy from command line

Tags: python, email, debian, dkim

How to use this python library from the command line?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dkimpy

I have a raw email message I want to validate the DKIM signature.. But how.. Can't find any docs about the usage

The raw message is a string/stream

Answer (score 2):

First I needed a test message, this is how I got one:

- Opened Gmail and selected an email.
- Clicked the vertical 3 dots on the top right side of the message view
- Selected *Show original*
- Clicked *Download Original* and saved it to `~/original_msg.txt`

I then opened up a terminal window and made sure I was in my home directory:

```
$ cd ~
```

Then I installed dkimpy:

```
$ pip install dkimpy
```

Annoyingly, `dkimverify --help` didn't work, but `man` came to the rescue:

```
$ man dkimverify
dkimverify(1)

NAME
       dkimverify - Script for DKIM verifying messages on stdin

DESCRIPTION
       dkimverify reads an RFC822 message on standard input, and returns with exit code 0 
       if the signature verifies successfully. Otherwise, it returns with exit code 1.
```

so I verified my downloaded Gmail message:

```
$ cat original_msg.txt | dkimverify
signature ok
$ echo $?
0
```

And just to make sure it failed as expected, I created a bogus message:

```
$ echo "bogus-header:bogus email" > bogus_msg.txt
```

And then tried to validate it:

```
$ cat bogus_msg.txt | dkimverify
signature verification failed
$ echo $?
1
```